# xcode clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Lockbox'

Tags: xcode, clang

i try to compile xcode project and i face this error
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Lockbox'

```
Ld /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/barqiaty.app/barqiaty normal x86_64 (in target 'Barqiaty' from project 'Barqiaty')
cd /Users/ahmad/Desktop/Barqiaty_iOSApp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios13.5-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -L/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BIObjCHelpers -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cosmos -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CountryPickerSwift -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManager -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lockbox -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mantle -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PINCache -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reachability -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBJson -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftGifOrigin -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast-Swift -F/Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VBRRollingPit -F/Users/ahmad/Desktop/Barqiaty_iOSApp/Pods/PayCardsRecognizer/Source -F/Users/ahmad/Desktop/Barqiaty_iOSApp/Booking -F/Users/ahmad/Desktop/Barqiaty_iOSApp -filelist /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Barqiaty.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Barqiaty.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/barqiaty.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Barqiaty.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Barqiaty.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/barqiaty_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Barqiaty.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Barqiaty.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/barqiaty.swiftmodule -framework AFNetworking -framework Alamofire -framework AnimatedCollectionViewLayout -framework BIObjCHelpers -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework Cosmos -framework CountryPicker -framework Foundation -framework IQKeyboardManager -framework Lockbox -framework MBProgressHUD -framework Mantle -framework PINCache -framework PayCardsRecognizer -framework QuartzCore -framework Reachability -framework SBJson -framework Security -framework SwiftGifOrigin -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Toast_Swift -framework UIKit -framework VBRRollingPit -weak_framework UIKit -framework AFNetworking -framework Alamofire -framework AnimatedCollectionViewLayout -framework BIObjCHelpers -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework Cosmos -framework CountryPicker -framework Foundation -framework IQKeyboardManager -framework -framework Lockbox -framework MBProgressHUD -framework Mantle -framework PINCache -framework QuartzCore -framework Reachability -framework SBJson -framework Security -framework SwiftGifOrigin -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Toast_Swift -framework UIKit -framework VBRRollingPit -weak_framework UIKit -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Barqiaty.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Barqiaty.build/barqiaty.app-Simulated.xcent -framework paytabs-iOS -framework Pods_Barqiaty -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Barqiaty.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Barqiaty.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/barqiaty_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ahmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barqiaty-fubhzmpblqlatcczpgpotdnzmnrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/barqiaty.app/barqiaty
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your question? That line is hard to read, why don't you add some newlines?

Answer (score 0):

I spotted something odd: `-framework -framework`. After that it cannot find `Lockbox` but it might misinterpret the second `-framework` as the argument and then tries to interpret  `Lockbox` not as an argument (doesn't trail with a - ) and not as a Framework but as an actual file it tries to find.

I would try to remove and add all frameworks again and clear derived data, to see if it goes away.